# Flow Builder - Dynamically Get Queue Id by Name

Tags: visual-workflow, record-type, queue

I am using flow builder to create cases and assign them to specific queues based on criteria within the flow.

In the Assignment element, I can set OwnerId to a hard coded id string or a resource.

I would like to use a resource to keep it dynamic, but am not seeing an obvious way to get the queue id by name.

At the beginning of the flow, I could run an invocable action that pulls the queues through SOQL and return a list of queues back to a resource, but this seems inefficient and excessive.

I looked into using a formula variable resource, but I'm not seeing a path in formulas to query a queue based on name either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the GetRecords Element and Query on the `Group` object.

Add the filter to make sure `Type = Queue`, then add the filter for `DeveloperName = (queue name)`.
[image]

Comment: I think that the accepted answer is wrong, and this answer is right. As noted by @cropredy, the name of the queue is not an option you can pick if you're targeting Queue. This technique using Group does let you pick the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve Queue Id dynamically by performing a lookup against Group object, check the query below

```
select Id , Name , Type from Group where Type= 'Queue'
```

Comment: OP asked for querying by queue name so you need to extend the Where clause